# WPF MVVM DataGrid изменение значения в ячейке приводит к OutOfMemoryException

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm

Использую паттерн mvvm и платформу для разработки *catel*. Размещаю *DataGrid* на форме в контейнере *Grid*.

```
<catel:UserControl x:Class="WriteOffWindow"
                   xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
                   xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
                   xmlns:catel="http://catel.codeplex.com"
                 xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
                   xmlns:i="clr-namespace:System.Windows.Interactivity;assembly=System.Windows.Interactivity"
                   xmlns:local="clr-namespace:Views"
                   xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
                   mc:Ignorable="d">
    <Grid>
        <DataGrid x:Name="gridDataContent"
                  Margin="10,0,10,35"
                  AutoGenerateColumns="False"
                  Background="White"
                  BorderBrush="#FFE6E6E6"
                  CanUserAddRows="False"
                  CanUserDeleteRows="False"
                  FontSize="16"
                  ItemsSource="{Binding ProductCollection}"
                  SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedProduct}"
                  SelectionUnit="FullRow">
            <i:Interaction.Triggers>
                <i:EventTrigger EventName="SelectionChanged">
                    <catel:EventToCommand Command="{Binding Mode=TwoWay, Path=SetFocus}" PassEventArgsToCommand="True" />
                </i:EventTrigger>
                <i:EventTrigger EventName="CellEditEnding">
                    <catel:EventToCommand Command="{Binding Mode=TwoWay, Path=EndEdit}" PassEventArgsToCommand="True" />
                </i:EventTrigger>
            </i:Interaction.Triggers>
            <DataGrid.Resources>
                <Style TargetType="DataGridRow">
                    <Style.Resources>

                        <SolidColorBrush x:Key="{x:Static SystemColors.InactiveSelectionHighlightBrushKey}"
                                         Opacity="0.5"
                                         Color="DodgerBlue" />
                        <SolidColorBrush x:Key="{x:Static SystemColors.InactiveSelectionHighlightBrush}" Color="DodgerBlue" />
                    </Style.Resources>
                </Style>
            </DataGrid.Resources>
            <DataGrid.Columns>
                <DataGridTextColumn Width="350"
                                    Binding="{Binding FullName}"
                                    Header="Наименование"
                                    IsReadOnly="True" />
                <DataGridTextColumn Binding="{Binding Capacity}"
                                    Header="Объём"
                                    IsReadOnly="True" />
                <DataGridTextColumn Binding="{Binding Quantity}"
                                    Header="Кол-во"
                                    IsReadOnly="True" />
                <DataGridTextColumn Binding="{Binding WriteOffQuantity}"
                                    Header="Кол-во списываемой продукции"
                                    IsReadOnly="False" />
            </DataGrid.Columns>
        </DataGrid>
    </Grid>
</catel:UserControl>
```

*ProductCollection* имеет тип *ObservableCollection<ProductModel>*.
Проблема в том, что когда делаю даблклик для изменения ячейки, процесс *devenv.exe* (при отладке) начинает расти в памяти до открытия ячейки на изменение, что приводит к падению VS 2015 с ошибкой *OutOfMemoryException*. 
Использую технологию *clickOnce*, после установки приложения на пк, уже само приложение начинает расти в памяти, возникает выше описанная ошибка, либо ячейка на изменение открывается очень долго.

В чем может быть проблема? Может кто нибудь сталкивался?

Вызов при инициализации

```
EndEdit = new Command<DataGridCellEditEndingEventArgs>(OnEndEditExecute, OnEndEditCanExecute);
SetFocus = new Command<SelectionChangedEventArgs>(OnSetFocusExecute, OnSetFocusCanExecute);
```

Сами методы:

```
private bool OnEndEditCanExecute(DataGridCellEditEndingEventArgs e)
{
    if (e != null)
    {
        if (SelectedProduct != null)
        {
            var text = (TextBox)e.EditingElement;
            if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(text.Text))
            {
                text.Text = text.Text.Replace(",", ".").Replace("-", "");
                if (e.Column.SortMemberPath.Equals("WriteOffQuantity"))
                {
                    try
                    {
                        if (SelectedProduct.Quantity < Convert.ToSingle(text.Text.Replace(".",",")))
                        {
                            MessageBox.Show("Нельзя списать больше чем есть на остатках", "Ошибка изменения значения", MessageBoxButton.OK, MessageBoxImage.Error);
                            text.Text = "0";
                            return false;

                        }
                        else
                        {
                          //  text.Text = text.Text.Replace(",", ".");
                            return true;
                        }
                    }
                    catch
                    {
                      //  text.Text = "0";
                        return false;
                    }

                }
                else
                {
                    return false;
                }
            }
            else
            {
                text.Text = "0";
                return false;
            }
        }
        else
        {
            return false;
        }
    }
    else
        return true;
}
```

Здесь скрол прокручивается до выделенного объекта

```
private bool OnSetFocusCanExecute(SelectionChangedEventArgs e)
{
    if (e == null)
        return true;
    var grid = e.Source as DataGrid;
    if (SelectedProduct != null)
    {
        grid?.ScrollIntoView(SelectedProduct);
    }
    return true;
}

private void OnEndEditExecute(DataGridCellEditEndingEventArgs e)
{
}

private void OnSetFocusExecute(SelectionChangedEventArgs e)
{
}
```

Забыл добавить, записей порядка 1000.

Comment: Код команд SetFocus и EndEdit можете добавить?

Comment: добавил в сам вопрос. Тоже грешил на них, но если их убрать, тоже ничего не меняется.

Comment: Отключение OnEndEditCanExecute не помогает? Он подозрительный у вас.

Comment: нет, не помогает.

Comment: Где-то у Вас возможно не явно происходит зацикливание

Comment: Еще очень сложно анализировать такой код, ведь можно все короче и лаконичнее написать

Comment: скорее всего зацикливание у Вас происходит из-за if (SelectedProduct != null)
    {
        grid?.ScrollIntoView(SelectedProduct);
    }

Comment: я же писал, даже если убрать эти методы, то ячейка на изменение, при даблклике, все равно очень долго открывается и процесс набирает память,даже если не возникает исключения то процесс может занимать 800МБ, при открытии другой ячейки обязательно выскочит исключение о нехватке памяти. Такое ощущение что начинает перебираться весь список в гриде(включая инклуды) в поиске выделенной ячейки

Comment: вопрос может не в тему, но почему у Вас  скролл происходит в OnSetFocusCanExecute. Должен ли скролл происходить при каждой проверки может ли команда SetFocus выполнится?  Нужен ли вам триггер для SelectionChanged

Comment: дело в том, что SelectedProduct может заполняться программно(например при поиске) и для того чтобы выделенный элемент всегда был на экране нужна прокрутка скрола